# Extract Javascript variables of a page via PHP

Tags: php

I want to extract a javascript variable from a page which would output something like this:-

```
<html>
...
...
<script>
var __id = '312484',__apikey='b7853089441ac55d28441495a95c9fc6', __filename='asbdadsd.mp4';
</script>
...
...
</html>
```

What can I do to extract the variable __filename from that page ?

Comment: `alert(__filename);`

Comment: Are you crawling the page or why do you need to extract that variable with PHP? And post some code with what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple PHP string functions.

Pass the variable name and the URL of the page to find it on.

```
function findVar($var, $url){
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    if(strpos($data, $var) == false) return false;
    $len = strlen($var) + 2;
    $start = strpos($data, $var."='") + $len; 
    $stop = strpos($data, "'", $start); 
    $val = substr($data, $start, ($stop-$start));
    return $val; 
}
```

Example:

```
$variable = "indicatorText";
$URL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"
$value = findVar($variable, $URL);
var_dump($value);
```

Returns

```
string(31) "<div class="loading-indicator">"
```

In the source code:

```
indicatorText='<div class="loading-indicator">'
```

Plug in your url and the variable to look for.

- Will search for any variable with no modifications to the function
- If variable name is not found in page returns false
- Assumes variables are strings defined with single quotes
- Assumes there are no spaces between the variable name, the "=" and the variable value
- It makes a lot of assumptions but you can change it as you require.

Comment: Will I have to change the +12 if I want any other variable ?

Comment: yes. 12 is the number of characters in "__filename='". If you chnage the variable you'll have to update the 12.

Comment: but this returns some random characters if __filename is not present in the file ! can you give me a alternative solution ?

Comment: @YashSodha See my update. If this answer helped you please click the check mark to select it.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but I guess it will just work perfectly fine